# How do I toggle the display to show in an if-else statement?

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to toggle the circle on click so the circle-check will appear and the circle will hide and so far haven't been able to figure it out. I already have the hover part in CSS in which the circle disappears and the checkmark appears.

HTML

```
<p class="reme">
  <a href="#" class="check">
    <i id="i" class="far fa-circle"></i>
    <i id="u" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    . 
  </a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remember Me
</p>
```

CSS

```
#i {
  color: #2ECC71;
  background-color: white;
}
#u {
  color: #2ECC71;
  background-color: white;
}
/*
.check:hover #i,
.check #u {
  display: none;
}
.check:hover #u {
  display: inline;
}
*/
```

JQUERY

```
/*
$(".check").click(function(){
  if ( $(".check").hasClass("fa-circle")  {
    $(".check").removeClass("fa-circle");
  } else {
    $(".check").toggleClass("fa-check-circle fa-circle");
  }
});

$(".check").click(function() {
  if ( $( this ).find('i').hasClass( "fa-circle" ) ) {
    $( this ).find('i').removeClass( "fa-circle" );
    $( this ).find('i').addClass( "fa-circle-check" );
  } else {
    $( this ).find('i').removeClass( "fa-circle-check" );
    $( this ).find('i').addClass( "fa-circle" );
  }
});
*/
$(".check").click(function(){
  $(".check").toggleClass("fa-circle fa-circle-check");
});
$(".check").click(function(){
  $(".check").show("fa-circle-check");
});
$(".check").hasClass(function(){
  $(".check").hide("fa-circle-check");
});
```

Comment: i don't get what you are trying to do. you have a "circle" and a "check-circle". Now what do you want to toggle? Are you trying to show one and hide the other every time you click on your link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use **toggle** instead of **toggleClass**

1. Hide icon with id using

   `$("#u").hide();`
2. Toggle icons with id -i and u 
   `$(".check").click(function(){
   $("#u").toggle();
   $("#i").toggle();
   });`

working code sample for reference-
codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VojwbJ

```js
$("#u").hide();
$(".check").click(function(){
  $("#u").toggle();
  $("#i").toggle();
});
```

```css
#i {
  color: #2ECC71;
  background-color: white;
}
#u {
  color: #2ECC71;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="reme">
  <a href="#" class="check">
    <i id="i" class="far fa-circle"></i>
    <i id="u" class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
    . 
  </a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remember Me
</p>
```

Comment: Oof I wish I saw this five minutes ago cuz this is what I did and yours is way easier $('#u').hide();
  $(".check").click(function() {

 if ( $("#u").css("display") == "none")  {

    $("#u").css("display", "inline-block");
    $("#i").css("display", "none");

  } else {

    $("#u").css("display", "none");
    $("#i").css("display", "inline-block");

  }

});

Comment: The initial toggleClass() seemed to be the more appropriate approach to avoid redundancy, since the id's "i" and "u" look to be adding the same styles and the desired effect is to simply show or hide the check mark when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using font-awesome and simply trying to change the style of the check icon on click there is no need for both  elements. Instead, use one and toggle its class by giving it a specific selector. Something like below.

```js
$('.check').on('click',function(){
  $(this).find('#toggle-me').toggleClass('fa-circle fa-check-circle');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="reme">
  <a href="#" class="check">
    <i id="toggle-me" class="far fa-circle"></i>
  </a>
</p>
```